# Ether not showing up on Nano ledger S

Tags: transactions, wallets, wallet-transfer, ledger-nano-s

I sent Ether from coin base to my ledger nano S. I have triple checked the address and it is correct. Conibase and etherscan show the transaction completed. However it is not showing up in my Ether wallet on my ledger nano s. Also when I look at my deposits on my ledger nano s and withdraws my balance at the top is short ~1/2 ether. Has anyone else seen this? I appreciate your help.